# if the request parameter header is as applicationx-www-form-urlencoded in json format how can i read it asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I set the Request header in postman as "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`", and the format of the Request parameter is **Json**, but I can't get the value in `asp.net` core, I currently get `request.form.keys.count () ==0` `requset.body.length ==0` but `requset.contentlength >0`

Comment: Why are you posting JSON and saying it's a form post? That doesn't add up.

Comment: This is what I encountered. The request header set by the other side is "applicationx-www-form-urlencoded", but the submitted parameters are Json, such as {"a":"a","b":"b"},

Comment: Then kick the other side until they send the proper header/body combination. Or see [Access Raw Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678990/access-raw-request-body)

Comment: lol,I'd like to, but my boss won't let me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, when I used routing matches like Controller/Action/id, I was unable to read the requested parameters
If I don't use it, I can read these parameters, and I suspect that this is a problem with the underlying code, and I can't solve it, so I don't use route matching, and I'm sad when I can't use route matching,I cannot get the requested parameters as follows=>

```
    [Route("test/{str}")]       
public async Task<IActionResult> test(string str)
{         
    return Content(str);
}
```