# How to cast a JSON to a string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have a Post method that receives a fairly simple JSON:

{
  "First": "John",
  "Last": "Smith"
}

But I need it as a string.

I've tried casting the JSON to a string but it comes up null.

```
   public void Post([FromBody]string jsonData)
    {
       ...
    }
```

I would like to use jsonData as a string. I am trying to avoid creating a class with field names matching the JSON because that would mean changing the API every time a field is added.  I just need to receive the JSON as a string at the outset. Is there a way to cast it as such at the endpoint without using variable names?

Comment: is this .net core or something else?

Comment: What exactly would this string contain? (given your example json)

Comment: It is Core.   The string would contain the JSON in string format.  Something I could serialize and de-serialize etc.

Comment: If the side that is requesting is javascript, add a `=` and stringify the json object

Comment: It is coming in from an external source as an API call.

Comment: Hm, then you'll have to create a new class with the properties having the same name and structure as what you're expecting to receive. Use the class you create as the parameter for that method.

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid.  That means every time they change the JSON I need to change my class.

Comment: You could receive as an object instead of string and see if you can parse it with that newtonsoft library.. I'm shooting in the dark here tbh

Comment: Can;t you just grab it from the Request? `var s = Request["parameter"];`

Comment: Actually casting it as an object is correct!

Comment: Did you check [ASP.NET Core MVC : How to get raw JSON bound to a string without a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31952002/3744182) or [Access Raw Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31678990)?

Comment: May my blog might be able to help you https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/01/22/parse-json-string-with-json-net/

Answer (score 1):

Just use JToken as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostMethod([FromBody] JToken json)
{
    var jsonAsString = json.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this?

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

You might want to refer to Json.NET [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)