# Is there any way to get request body in .NET Core FilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Sample of my request

```
http://localhost:8065/api/note
POST
content-type:application/json
request body: { "id" : "1234", "title" : "test", "status" : "draft"}
```

and the response should be

```
{ "msg" : "ok", "code" : 1}
```

The action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]NoteModel model)
```

---

To have every request logged automatically, I created an attribute to do this job. The attribute looks like this: (from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#Dependency%20injection))

```
public class SampleActionFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public SampleActionFilterAttribute():base(typeof(SampleActionFilterImpl))
    {
    }

    private class SampleActionFilterImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public SampleActionFilterImpl(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SampleActionFilterAttribute>();
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
        
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("[path]" + context.HttpContext.Request.Path);
            _logger.LogDebug("[method]" + context.HttpContext.Request.Method);
            _logger.LogDebug("[body]"); //log request body, expectation: { "id" : "1234", "title" : "test", "status" : "draft"}
            _logger.LogDebug("[statuscode]" + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
            _logger.LogDebug("[response]"); //log response
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use streamReader to get the request body only got an empty string.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Is that because the body was read by [fromBody] from the controller so the stream can not be read twice? If so, how am I supposed to get the request body and response in `OnActionExecuted` method?

---

Update:

I've just copied Set's code into my project, not working. Here is the debug gif[image]

Comment: Also, it has been well answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/4074527.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Accordingly to this "[Best way to log/read request body in a middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4962)" thread, the following should work:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;

public class SampleActionFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    ... 

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // read body before MVC action execution
        string bodyData = ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request);
    }

    private string ReadBodyAsString(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var initialBody = request.Body; // Workaround

        try
        {
            request.EnableRewind();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return text;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Workaround so MVC action will be able to read body as well
            request.Body = initialBody; 
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
 }
```

Also similar approach described in [Read request body twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389781/read-request-body-twice) SO post

---

**Update**: above approach in `ReadBodyAsString` with will work if used in middleware, not in action filter. The difference is that when action filter is calling (even for `OnActionExecuting`), the body stream already has been read and `[FromBody] model` has been populated.

The good nesw is that so it is possible to get model directly in action filter by using `context.ActionArguments["<model_name>"]`. In your case:

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
   var model = context.ActionArguments["model"] as NoteModel;
}
```

Comment: Just tried this sulution. The `ReadBodyAsString` method in `OnActionExecuting` still get noting, see the gif I pasted. (The `[fromBody] model` has value).

Comment: @wtf512 updated answer. You may use `context.ActionArguments` directly to get model in action filter, or if you want to do manipulations with raw request body, move to middleware approach for logging.

Comment: The `context.ActionArguments` solved my problem.  I just loop every item in ActionArgumetns and use newtonsoft.json to serialize as string and log.

Answer (score 2):

Following snippet worked for me, to log request only if there is any exception.(.Net Core 3.1)

{

```
public class ExceptionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> requests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception != null)

        {
            StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();

            _logger.LogError("Error while executing action:" + context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName);

            string errRequest;
            if(requests.TryGetValue(context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,out errRequest))
            {
                _logger.LogError(errRequest);
            }

            _logger.LogError(context.Exception);

            context.Result = new ObjectResult("Error!!!")
            {
                StatusCode = 500,
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        string req;
            requests.Remove(context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier, out req);


    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var arg in context.ActionArguments)
        {

            sb.Append(arg.Key.ToString() + ":" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg.Value) + "\n");

        }
        requests.TryAdd(context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier, sb.ToString());
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
    in .net core 3.1, I usually use this approach to handle this scenario
    
    1- Create Async Filter Attribute
    
    public class MyFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
        {
            private string _errorMessage = UserAccessErrorMessages.NO_ACCESS;
            public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
            {
                string requestBody = await ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request);
                var reportFiltration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(requestBody);
                var _myService = (IMyService)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMyService));
                    if (!hasAccess)
                    {
                        context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(_errorMessage);
                    }
            }
    
            private async Task<string> ReadBodyAsString(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest request)
            {
                var initialBody = request.Body; // Workaround
    
                try
                {
                    //request.EnableRewind();
    
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
                    {
                        string text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        return text;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Workaround so MVC action will be able to read body as well
                    request.Body = initialBody;
                }
            }
        }
2- Create Your Custom Attribute
public class MyAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute, IAllowAnonymous
    {
        public MyAttribute () : base(typeof(MyFilter))
        {

        }
    }
```

3- use your filter

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("MyAction")]
    [MyAttribute]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostData([FromBody]MyModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IActionResult in your controllers and you want the .NET objects, you can write a filter like this:

```
public class SampleFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult)
        {
            var objResult = (ObjectResult)context.Result;
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

By the point it hits OnActionExecuted, the ObjectResult task has already completed, so you can just extract the value. You can also get the StatusCode with objResult.StatusCode.

In the controller, return Ok(...) actually creates an OkObjectResult, etc.

If you specifically want the serialzied result, then Set's answer is more valid.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to map the request json

```
object obj = context.ActionArguments["query"]; 
if (obj != null) {
   APIBaseResponse bc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIBaseResponse>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
   No= bc.No;
   Code = bc.Code; 
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

.net core 7:

```
private async Task<string> ReadBodyAsString(HttpRequest request)
{
    try
    {

        request.EnableBuffering();
        string text = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        
        return text;
    }
    finally
    {
        request.Body.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

End Full code CustomAttribute source code:

```
public class AuthorizeStationAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute, IAllowAnonymous
{
    public AuthorizeStationAttribute() : base(typeof(StationPassRequirementFilter))
    {
    }
}

public class StationPassRequirementFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string requestBody = await ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request);

        var baseRequestFromStation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseRequestFromStation>(requestBody);

        if (baseRequestFromStation == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseRequestFromStation.DeviceId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseRequestFromStation.Password))
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            return;
        }

        IStationsRepository stationsRepository = (IStationsRepository)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IStationsRepository));

        if (stationsRepository.IsStationExist(baseRequestFromStation.Password, baseRequestFromStation.DeviceId) == false)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }


    private async Task<string> ReadBodyAsString(HttpRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();
            string text = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            return text;
        }
        finally
        {
            request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```