# ActionFilter Get API Response Object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, action-filter

How do I get the value of an actual Object in ActionFilterAttribute?
In the Debugger, I see value in actionExecutedContext.Result.Value.

However, when trying to actually type them in as

`actionExecutedContext.Result.Value` or `actionExecutedContext.Result.GetValue()`, it cannot recognize them.

I need the actual object, so it can be sent to one of my Static Data methods, which accepts an inputs, and multiplies all numbers by 2.

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext actionContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
   var actionExecutedContext= await next();
   // ObjectDataConverter.MultiplyIntegersBy2(test.Result.Value);
}
```

[image]

> actionExecutedContext.Result.Value error CS1061: 'IActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'IActionResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Resources: [Read Asp.Net Core Response body in ActionFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626497/read-asp-net-core-response-body-in-actionfilterattribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast actionExecutedContext.Result to ObjectResult and use ObjectResult.Value if cast is successful:

```
var objResult = actionExecutedContext.Result as ObjectResult;
if (objResult != null && objResult.Value != null) {
  // process objResult.Value here
}
```