# Using Request.Body in custom ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Consider the custom model binder below:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]
public class StreamModel
{
    public MemoryStream Stream
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new StreamModel
        {
            Stream = ms
        });
    }
}
```

Value of `ms.Length` always equals to `0`.
Are there any ways to read request Body in a ModelBinder?

Also the below scenario seems weird to me:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(string data)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
        return OK(ms.Length);
    }
}
```

It always returns `0`.
But when removing parameter `string data`, it returns actual length of posted body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read request body twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389781/read-request-body-twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to read the request body multiple times.

For a workaround and more information, you should take a look at this question:
[Read request body twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389781/read-request-body-twice/)

Comment: using `app.Use(next => context => { context.Request.EnableRewind(); return next(context); });` works but I didn't read the request.Body multiple times. (I think mvc does this internally). (gonna create an issue for this in mvc repo on github)