# Is there a way to ensure the HTTP request body can be loaded into memory for possible multiple read requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, httpcontext, system.net.httpwebrequest

Is there a way to ensure the HTTP request body can be loaded into memory? There are multiple middle-wares which will use same HTTP Request body to log at multiple levels.

I remember doing following in .Net Framework 4.6

```
await request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();


/// *** Method snapshot from HttpContent - System.Net.Http library ***
/// <summary>Serialize the HTTP content to a memory buffer as an asynchronous operation.</summary>
/// <returns>The task object representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
public Task LoadIntoBufferAsync()
{
  return this.LoadIntoBufferAsync((long) int.MaxValue);
}
```

Can anyone help me find similar behavior in .Net Core?

## EDIT

-- I think right answer here is to use EnableBuffering, but I am not to able to figure out which overloaded method should I use for EnableBuffering?

```
    public static void EnableBuffering(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        BufferingHelper.EnableRewind(request);
    }

    public static void EnableBuffering(this HttpRequest request, int bufferThreshold)
    {
        BufferingHelper.EnableRewind(request, bufferThreshold);
    }

    public static void EnableBuffering(this HttpRequest request, long bufferLimit)
    {
        BufferingHelper.EnableRewind(request, bufferLimit: bufferLimit);
    }
```

Size of HTTP Request in our application is varying from 50kb to 300mb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read request body multiple times in asp net core 2.2 middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442553/how-to-read-request-body-multiple-times-in-asp-net-core-2-2-middleware)

Comment: Accepted answer is not enough, right answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60923370/395773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asp.net core 2.x you can use :

```
HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
```

For asp.net core 3.x you can use :

```
HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
```

That methods ensure the request Body can be read multiple times. Normally buffers request bodies in memory :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestrewindextensions.enablebuffering?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering(); works with .Net Core 2.1 as well.